# Print ASCII extended table with C++ (won't print cyrillics - ukrainian letters)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, kde, character-encoding, c++

So, I am to print `ASCII` extended table in `C++`, it must include Ukrainian letters (cyrilics).
I am on `KDE neon 5.26` linux distribution, it is based on `Ubuntu`. Terminal is KDE's `Console` obiviously.

[image: About my system]

I made that code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(void) {

        for (unsigned char i = 32; int(i) < 255; i++) {
                std::cout <<" [" << i << "] " << int(i) << " \t";
                if ((i-1)%5 == 0)
                        std::cout << "\n";
        }

        char ua_str[] = "Привіт";  // hello in ukrainian
        std::cout << "\n\n" << ua_str << "\n" << ua_str[4] << " is " << int(ua_str[4]) << "\n";

        return std::cout.fail() ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiled it with `g++ lab3.cpp`. It produces such output:

[image]

I am interested, how it printed `char ua_str[]` but won't print `ua_str[4]`.

Terminal encoding is set to `UTF8`, I cannot find `ASCII` in Terminal encoding settings. If I redirect output to `abc.txt` text file with `./a.out > abc.txt` and open it, it looks like the next:
[image]

So, I ran `locale -a` in terminal:
[image]

Then I ried to add `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "uk_UA.utf8");` to my program in `int main(void)` before the `for` loop but It didn't changed anything, output is the same...

I am to make transliteration script later but can't print and work properly with ukrainian letters...

So, question is: How to print and work with cyrillic cahrs in `C++` on `KDE neon 5.26`?

Comment: ASCII doesn't contain cyrilics, you need UTF-8, a specific code page, or unicode. I'd shorten the question to how to print a single specific character with a more generic title that avoids using ASCII in the title.

Comment: Solved by changing terminal encoding to `KOI8-U`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74420151/16781134

Comment: Great. I just noticed Marcus’s answer, it is a good breakdown of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that UTF-8 is not an extended ASCII encoding (there is very many different interpretations of bytes >127), so what you try won't work. You're telling your terminal to interpret something as UTF-8 that isn't.

What you need to do is figure out which specific encoding you're expected to use. I'd guess your teacher means ISO/IEC 8859-5, but I can't know for sure. The only way to know is to ask - or use the encoding you told your text editor to use when it displays the right characters. It's an easy way to try.

By itself, an editor, a console or a human can't know whether you mean ISO/IEC 8859-5 or some other ASCII extension (to be more correct: *code page*).

To cite [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) on this:

> Using the term "extended ASCII" is sometimes criticized, because it can be mistakenly interpreted to mean that the ASCII standard has been updated to include more characters, or that the term unambiguously identifies a single encoding, neither of which is the case.

And you see that ambiguity in action here.

So, honestly, maybe not the best exercise for a C++ beginner. The world has luckily mostly moved on to UTF so that this ambiguity no longer affects us. (The downside of that is only that the exact program you're writing is harder to write, because you need to know what unicode codepoints to enumerate. I'm not sure how often you want to specify cyrillic letters by their byte values, I'd expect that this approaches "never" in reality.)

Now, either you break your console by configuring it to use 8859-1, or you learn how to translate 8859-1 to utf-8 and print that. The latter would be the more sensible thing to do! Your source code remains UTF-8, which is why saying hello in a string worked out of the box.

So, how to translate "legacy" extended ASCII encodings to UTF-8? I'll have to look that up. I'm German, there's umlauts in my name, and I never felt the urge to use anything other than UTF-8 since that became an option.

Comment: Got it. Tnaks for the info.

Comment: @VladyslavRehan you're most welcome, and all the best for your programming!

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is a multi-byte coding.
Add to your source a loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ua_str); i++) {
            std::cout << ua_str[i] << " is " << (0xFF & ua_str[i]) << "\n";
    }
```

As you can see now, the string of 6 characters is actually an array of 12 bytes. Each letter is represented by two bytes.

'П' is 208-159, 'р' is 209-128, etc

The straight `ua_str[4]` refers to a page byte of the 3rd letter.

Comment: I added it and it still prints question marks...

Comment: @VladyslavRehan Of course it does. The loop does not change anything, it just shows what actually is inside the string. It is an illustration to what Marcus Müller described in words.